# How can i add a extra form on checkout page?

Tags: magento2, checkout, forms

I would like to be able to add some forms in the checkout page, saving the information in the BD. I have Magento 2.2.4

How could I do it? Where is the file that I would have to modify?

Thanks!

Comment: On checkout where you want to add your forms?

Comment: when you enter the information of the user who is going to make a purchase @DhirenVasoya

Comment: I means which place you want to add your form? before shipping? or where?

Comment: Sorry, i would like add a form before the payment page.

Comment: Do you want to add that on before payment section, right?

Comment: yes @DhirenVasoya

Answer (score 1):

Here is the start point for you...

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/howdoi/checkout/checkout_form.html

Comment: I copied all the code from this page. But I stayed in step 3 because I do not know what code to put. Someone can help me?